# domain-calls that land on the same system shall be divided to assosiated sub-controllers

Tags: php, architecture, multiple-domains

My question is not easy to tell, but I will try to do it by telling the process.

There are x domains who are bound to the same IP on a apache server. With url-rewrite all calls are landing on the index.php file.

There is a mvc-pattern and so I have a main controller, who handles url-routing, templete delivery, and so on. Sub-Controllers inherit from it and do the individual stuff, like admin-methods, user-profile actions, and actions according to the differences in the systems identified by the domain.

For example domain1.com can handle users who can create sub users and give permissions to documents.
The system in domain2.com has only users who can do questionaries and change profile settings.
Then there is a admin-domain to administrate all the systems on the domainx.com domains and there is some presentational domain, where blog entries are provided (adinistrated over the admin-domain).

All the domains also deliver different html-headers for different look and feel.

All Systems are similar or need each others in some way.

So far, I have a sub-folder in the url to know which system is ment. But I have troubles with linking and the login-system, so I want to redesign the whole thing.

Is there any pattern recommended? Are there best-practices for such a problem?

Thanks for Ideas and Answers.

**Pleas also try to help to improve the question by posting comments, especialy if you -1 this issue. ;)**

Comment: IIUC the modules on the various domains share nothing but some data (presumably a database), not even sessions?

Comment: They Land on the same Software. And usw the same database